# Set Livewire value in JavaScript with defer

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a date picker inside a Livewire component which I'm setting the value of via JavaScript as the Bootstrap datepicker does not update the value automatically:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
            down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
            previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
            next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
            today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
            clear: 'fa fa-trash',
            close: 'fa fa-remove'
        }
    }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
        this.due_date = e.target.value;
    });
```

This works great, however the picker disappears when the Livewire update occurs (as expected). Is there a way to update `due_date` via JavaScript but have it deferred in the same way as setting `wire:model.defer="due_date"` so it's sent on the next network update rather than instantly?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
@this.set('prop', value, true)
```

The third argument of `true` is for defer.